# store data from url line by line in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, python-requests

I'm trying to read data line by line from url and store each line in a list:
I tried:

```
url = request.GET.get('url')

data = [] 
with closing(requests.get(url, stream=True)) as f:
    data = [list(map(int, line.split('\n'))) for line in f]
```

input:

```
1 1 1 
2 2 2
3 3 3
```

expected output :

```
data = [[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]
```

Comment: What output do you get? The expected output isn't a valid list

Comment: I'm getting one list only i.e [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3] @Sayse

Answer (score 1):

Since you dont show your data source or your input its not easy to say what your doing wrong. however the following is an example of reading a csv file of data from a source, it will read line by line and then split each line by comma and store it as a list. This is all done in a list comprehension so you end up with a list of lists.

**NOTE:** This is just an example for CSV normally i would use csv module for parsing. But this should give you an idea of how you would read each line of data as it comes back and split it.

In your code you will be reading each line one at a time then you say you want to split by new line. but there will be no new line to split by as your only getting one line at a time.

```py
import requests
from contextlib import closing

with closing(requests.get('http://samplecsvs.s3.amazonaws.com/SacramentocrimeJanuary2006.csv', stream=True)) as f:
    data = [line.decode().split(',') for line in f]
print(data)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[['cdatetime', 'address', 'district', 'beat', 'grid', 'crimedescr', 'ucr_ncic_code', 'latitude', 'longitude\r1/1/06 0:00', '3108 OCCIDENTAL DR', '3', '3C        ', '111'], ['5', '10851(A)VC TAKE VEH W/O OWNER', '2404', '38.55042047', '-121.3914158\r1/1/06 0:00', '2082 EXPEDITION WAY', '5', '5A        ', '1512', '459 PC  BURGLARY'], [' RESIDENCE', '2204', '38.47350069', '-121.4901858\r1/1/06 0:00', '4 PALEN CT', '2', '2A        ', '212', '10851(A)VC TAKE VEH W/O OWNER', '2404', '38.65784584', ''],..........
```

Comment: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str' @Chris Doyle

Comment: [['1 1 1\r\n2 2 2\r\n3 3 3']] This is what i'm getting now